# Не удается установить Pygame в Termux

Tags: python, pygame, termux

Я попытался установить Pygame на Termux, но у меня ничего не получилось. Вот ошибка:

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, 
Running "config.py"       
Using UNIX configuration...                                                                                           
Missing dependencies                                                                                                  
Hunting dependencies...                                    
SDL     : found 1.2.15                                     
FONT    : not found                                        
IMAGE   : not found                                        
MIXER   : not found                                        
PNG     : not found                                        
JPEG    : not found                                        
SCRAP   : found                                            
PORTMIDI: not found                                        
PORTTIME: not found                                        
FREETYPE: found 2.10.4                                     
----------------------------------------
               
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/b8/b110cdea95452f8f9f9e79d02062fdccaebfd808a667d6d9a805ca8d222a/pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz#sha256=2050c68ff6eba1f801efc14fd1f805aaa3a94936c80ed6725b64a75ca1bce66f (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info 
Check the logs for full command output.                                                  
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4.dev0, 1.9.4rc1, 1.9.4, 1.9.5rc1, 1.9.5rc2, 1.9.5, 1.9.6rc1, 1.9.6rc2, 1.9.6, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0.dev3, 2.0.0.dev4, 2.0.0.dev6, 2.0.0.dev8, 2.0.0.dev10, 2.0.0.dev12, 2.0.0.dev14, 2.0.0.dev16, 2.0.0.dev18, 2.0.0.dev20, 2.0.0.dev22, 2.0.0.dev24, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev1, 2.0.1)                   
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame
```

Поискал в интернете и там пишется, что проблему можно решить если установить пакеты sdl-dev, libpng и libpng-dev, но у меня это так же не получается.

```
libpng-dev: E: Package 'libpng-dev' has no installation candidate
sdl-dev: E: Unable to locate package sdl-dev
```

Удалось установить только libpng, но это не помогло решить проблему.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `pkg install sdl2 sdl2-image sdl2-ttf wget xorgproto` https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/ks6xi4/pygame_on_termux/

Comment: У меня теперь вышла ошибка ```POSTMIDI: not found```. Да и последующие этапы неудачной установки (как в вопросе) все так же остались. С ошибками.

Comment: Какую версию `Python` вы используете?

Comment: Я использую Python 3.9.7

Comment: Попробуйте установить VNC сервер командой `pkg install tigervnc`, потом на смартфон установить VNC Viewer, и установить любое окружение, например Xfce. Потом запустить сервер командой `vncserver -geometry 1280x720 && export DISPLAY=:1`, запустить это окружение. И попытаться снова установить PyGame.

Answer (score 0):

У вас написано, что `pip` пытается установить `PyGame` версии *1.9.2*, попробуйте установить версию *2.0.1*

Я с Windows (`Python 3.9.6`) попытался установить `PyGame` командой: `pip install pygame==1.9.2` и у меня появилась примерно похожая ошибка

Также я написал: `pip install pygame==2.0.1` и у меня всё получилось.

Не знаю получиться ли на `Termux`, но у меня сработало

**ИЗМЕНЕНО:** На `Termux` мне помогло:

```bsh
pkg install sdl2 sdl2-image sdl2-ttf wget xorgproto
pip install cython  
wget [https://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz](https://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz)  
tar -xzf pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz  
cd pygame-1.9.6  
python3 setup.py -config -auto -sdl2  
python3 setup.py install cython
```

Comment: Не получится. У вас на WIndows это работает, потому что pygame был специально скомпилирован для Windows, а для Termux его никто не компилировал

Comment: Сейчас скачаю Termux, проверю

Comment: Не заработало, выходит такая же ошибка.