# Нужен игровой движок python, который работает в termux

Tags: python, разработка-игр, 3d, 2d, termux

Я уже давно пользуюсь утилитой vncserver в termux для того, чтобы работала графическая оболочка.
С этой утилитой можно создать виртуальные дисплеи, но когда к ним ничего не подключено (никакая утилита для виртуальных экранов, например xfce4), то экран показывается черным.

Это меня натолкнуло на мысль: Есть ли библиотека на Python, которая будет работать в Termux, обрабатывать 2D/3D графику и выводить ее на виртуальный экран?

Comment: Да хоть банальный pygame наверное? Только в виртуальном экране производительность будет фиговая, без аппаратного ускорения жить тяжко

Comment: Pygame мне просто не установить. Задавал вопрос, хорошего ответа не последовало. Вот кстати и вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306110/Не-удается-установить-pygame-в-termux